# Filter array based on sub array of objects properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following array of objects, I'm trying to work out how to filter the top array based on the Event array having an object containing an ID of 30

```
var staff = [];
staff.push({
    Id: 122,
    Events: [
        {Id: 30,Name: "Foo"},
        {Id: 57,Name: "Bar"}
    ]});
staff.push({
    Id: 122,
    Events: [
        {Id: 57,Name: "Bar"}
    ]});
```

So far I've tried variations of the following:

```
$.grep(staff, function (item) {
    return item.Events.Id == 30
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Expected output:

```
var staff = [{Id: 122, Events: [{Id: 30,Name: "Foo"},{Id: 57,Name: "Bar"}]}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var staff = [];
staff.push({
  Id: 122,
  Events: [
    { Id: 30, Name: 'Foo' },
    { Id: 57, Name: 'Bar' }
  ]
});
staff.push({
  Id: 122,
  Events: [{ Id: 57, Name: 'Bar' }]
});

const res = staff.filter((item) => item.Events.some((e) => e.Id === 30));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: perfect thanks, makes sense needed to filter the inner object the same as the outer

Comment: [`staff.filter(item => item.Events.some(e => e.Id === 30))`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) would be a lot better here, as it would return early if a match is found.